# On-topic? "How can I express that something is inconvenient in front of Japanese so as to not be overbearing?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The proposed QA site [Culture and life in Japan](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34330/culture-and-life-in-japan) has this sample question:

> How can I express that something is inconvenient in front of Japanese so as to not be overbearing?

First comment says:

> This seems more relevant to Japanese Language and Usage imo

So, would this question be on-topic here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could well go either way.  For example, if you think of the context of someone from a US company meeting with business partners from Japan, there could still be cultural issues to deal with even if all the discussion happened in English.

For this site, I think it would need a mild tweak to add something like more specifics of the situation, or an example of the type of sentence the original asker thinks might come off as 'overbearing', otherwise it's a bit vague/broad.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're asking for the particular linguistic construction that you would use to convey this nuance then it is on topic. If you're looking for a deeper conversation about culture then it belongs elsewhere.